# Laravel api resource not coming in json format when used in a controller

Tags: laravel

I have created an api resource like
http://app.localhost/api/product/info/1000

And it works fine and returns the desired data json format.

But, when I try to execute the resource in a controller like,

```
$Product = Product::where('sku', $this->sku)->get()->first();
$productInfo = new ProductRes($Product);
```

It return the full `$Product` Object, instead of json data. I have posted the screenshot of the object i have received.
[image]

Is it possible to render the resource in the same way as it does in the url?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `execute the resource in a controller`? Return it?

Comment: By execute i mean when an trying to return it through my controller.
$Product = Product::where('sku', $this->sku)->get()->first();
$productInfo = new ProductRes($Product);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `dump` or `dd` your variable `$productInfo`, it's normal it does not show you its rendered version. If you really want to dump its render, you may do this

```php
$Product = Product::where('sku', $this->sku)->get()->first();
$productInfo = new ProductRes($Product);
dump($productInfo->resolve());
```

Comment: Thank you, this has fixed my issue

Comment: You're welcome, remember tagging a post as your accepted answer.

Comment: `->get()` is redundant. It is sufficient `Product::where('sku', $this->sku)->first()`;

Answer (score 1):

Laravel converts responses to JSON, if you dump the object within the controller, it will show what it really is...an object.

If you don't dump the variable, but rather do a `return $productInfo`, it should cast to JSON.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand how it works, thank you for the quick reply

Comment: No problem. Accept the answer if it was the one you were looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Your product is always an object but laravel is using [__toString](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) magic method which basically means that what should I do when a user wants to echo an object, this is exactly what you are trying to do.

You are trying to `echo $product` which triggers `__toString` magic method and laravel converts it to `json` for you

```php
  /**
     * Convert the collection to its string representation.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->toJson();
    }
```

But when you `dd($product)` you are not echoing $product which means in this case you see the full object dumping out on the screen.