# How to fix Laravel resource is not working properly in blade view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-resource, laravel-response

I'm confused why casted props are inaccessible in the blade file. When I try to check it in the controller its showing properly.

Here's the JSON shown in the browser: `return $users;` (here `status` is string)
[image]

But when I tried to show it in the view, the status goes back to `int` which is the original value.
[image]

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
  <h1>{{ $user->status }}</h1>
@endforeach
```

And when I tried to `dd` in the blade view it shows the original model values.

---

Here's my resource file (shortened version):

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'status' => StatusEnum::value($this->status),
        ...
    ];
}
```

Here's my controller look like:

```
public function index()
{
    $record = User::all();
    $users = UserResource::collection($record);

    return view('pages.user.index', compact('users'));
}
```

---

I already tried solutions from other related [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61288344/laravel-api-resource-not-coming-in-json-format-when-used-in-a-controller) e.g. `->resolve()` but not working properly.

Comment: Are you providing real data sample? because, the first value of `status` was 'save', how come it turns to `021`?

Comment: @IbrahimHammed original data coming from DB is int. I cast it to readable string in the resource file by using enum (pls check code above :) ). Controller is okay. but in view blade file its not.

Comment: What is the `filename` of your resource file?

Comment: `dd()` is your friend. What is the value if you put the resource in a `dd()`?

Comment: @xenooooo pls read description :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, and could fix it, now I share my solution with you:

In your controller, convert the collection of resources to JSON using the toJson method:

```php
$items = ProductResource::collection($yourCollection)->toJson();
return view('view.show', compact('items'));
```

In your Blade view decode the collection:

```
@php
 $items=json_decode($items) 
 @endphp
...
  @foreach ($items as $item)
     ...
  @endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure user model doesn't has `getStatusAttribute()` function nor `status()` if it returns a related model.

Keep in mind that this may be due to inherited or imported classes and traits in User model

Comment: answer is not related. this is json resource collection. not attribute.